# Sending mail is not working ipad[IOS 9] device previous it was working

Tags: ios9, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using xcode 7.2 and trying to send mail using ipad[IOS 9] device ,It is not working and any error is also not coming.Any idea is with you please suggest me.

```
-(IBAction)Sendmail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mfMailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mfMailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;
        mfMailViewController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        NSMutableArray *rec=[NSMutableArray array];
        [rec addObject:@"deepak.kumar08@gmail.com"];



        [mfMailViewController setSubject:@"Testing mail"];
        [mfMailViewController setToRecipients: rec];
        [mfMailViewController setMessageBody:@"dskfksdfshdkfsd" isHTML:NO];
        [self presentViewController:mfMailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: it's difficult to answer without knowledge of the code

Comment: - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(nullable NSError *)error __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0)
{]

Answer (score 0):

It was not issue of application .It was issue with mailbox for working fine this mail composer ,mailbox must be configured with valid email id because It takes sender email-id from logged in mail box.